# Paging loader using RxSwift

Tags: swift, pagination, reactive-programming, rx-swift

This is generic logic for handling network requests that load data based on pages. It is assumed that the view controller would implement the `UISource` protocol. I have a test suite as well. I'm especially interested in any ideas for doing away with the `Variable`. I'm also interested in ideas for refactoring this code into smaller functions.

```
import RxSwift


protocol UISource {
    var refreshTrigger: Observable<Void> { get } // reloads most recently loaded page
    var nextPageTrigger: Observable<Void> { get } // loads next page
    var bag: DisposeBag { get }
}

protocol NetworkSource {
    associatedtype Item
    func loadData(page: Int) -> Observable<[Item]>
}

enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

struct PaginationNetworkSink<T> {

    let loading: Observable<Bool> // true if network loading is in progress.
    let elements: Observable<[T]> // elements from all loaded pages
    let error: Observable<Error> // fires once for each error
}

func paginationNetworkLogic<T, API>(ui: UISource, api: API) -> PaginationNetworkSink<T> where API: NetworkSource, T == API.Item {
    let loadResults = Variable<[Int: [T]]>([:])

    let refreshOffset = ui.refreshTrigger
        .map { loadResults.value.keys.max() }
        .filter { $0 != nil }
        .map { $0! }

    let nextOffset = ui.nextPageTrigger.map { () -> Int in
        if let page = loadResults.value.keys.max() {
            return page + 1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    let pageToLoad = Observable.of(refreshOffset, nextOffset)
        .merge()
        .startWith(0)

    let loadResult = pageToLoad.flatMapLatest {
        api.loadData(page: $0)
            .map { Result.success($0) }
            .catchError { Observable.just(Result.failure($0)) }
    }.share()

    let successResult = loadResult.map { (result) -> [T] in
        if case .success(let array) = result {
            return array
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }

    let pageAndResult = Observable.zip(pageToLoad, successResult) { (page: $0.0, array: $0.1) }
        .filter { !$0.array.isEmpty }

    pageAndResult.subscribe(onNext: {
        loadResults.value[$0.page] = $0.array
    }).disposed(by: ui.bag)

    let startLoading = pageToLoad
        .map { _ in true }

    let loadingComplete = loadResult.map { _ in false }

    let loading = Observable.of(startLoading, loadingComplete)
        .merge()
        .startWith(true)

    let elements: Observable<[T]> = loadResults.asObservable().map { results in
        var result: [T] = []
        let keys = results.keys.sorted()
        for key in keys {
            result += results[key]!
        }
        return result
    }.startWith([])

    let error = loadResult.map { result -> Error? in
        if case .failure(let error) = result {
            return error
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }

    return PaginationNetworkSink(loading: loading, elements: elements, error: error)
}
```